# Split surface at specific UV points?

Tags: python, uv

I'm having an interesting challenge with modeling that I'm hoping some of you might know a good answer to. Thank you in advance for the help.

### Backstory:

I'm working on a personal project to transform free 3d models (mainly from the Sketchup 3D Warehouse) into usable objects for flight simulators. The end goal is to set up a community repository where non-modellers can simply upload a Collada file and have it converted on the backend for the sims. This allows the community to drive the projects future.

### The problem:

The simulators only accept a single texture for each model. This is a challenge as a majority of the files on the warehouse and through Sketchup have multiple textures and multiple UVs. The modeller could potentially create a texture atlas and remap the textures by hand, but I'd prefer the project to be "fool proof" so beginners can contribute by doing this automatically.

One solution would be to use blender's Texture Atlas tool, and render the textures to a single file. I have an issue with this for two reasons. The first: merging the textures in this way is permanent, and defeats the purpose of using a common repository on Collada files and textures for future edits. Secondly, each file requires 3 maps (one main texture, a night texture, and a diffuse texture). If the user were to edit one texture, all 3 atlases would need to adjust accordingly.

The biggest issue I am facing is that these individual textures can be repeating. I have managed to create a texture atlas, but this will not work with the existing UVs, as it will not actually repeat the texture.

### My question:

Is there a way using python (or in general) to split a surface at specific UV points?
What I mean is, if a surface has a UV from 0 to 2.5 (thus repeating 2.5 times), how can I split the surface at UV points 1 and 2, thus creating 3 new surfaces that I can then UV map with the texture from 0 to 1, 0 to 1, and 0 to 0.5?